# Returning a list of every possible coordinate in a grid of that width and height

Tags: haskell, cartesian-product, cartesian-coordinates

So I am writing a function `allCoords` that returns a list of every possible coordinate in a grid of width `w` and height `h` Both `width` and `height` must be non-negative integers in order to return a sensible result.

Example: `allCoords 3 2` should return `[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)]`

This is all I've got so far but I don't know how to even start writing the function

```
type GridCoord = (Int, Int)

allCoords :: Int -> Int -> [GridCoord]
```

Comment: edits should not invalidate existing answers. if you already "have it" then what would be the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do that using a [list comprehension](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension).

```
[ (x,y) | x <- [0..1], y <- [0..2] ]
```

Will give the list in your example.

Your function would then need to be defined as:

```
type GridCoord = (Int, Int)

allCoords :: Int -> Int -> [GridCoord]
allCoords height width = [ (x,y) | x <- [0..width-1], y <- [0..height-1] ]
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`range`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Ix.html#v:range) function does that.

```
import Data.Ix
allCoords h w = range ((0,0), (w,h))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of the `Functor` and `Applicative` instance of a list to generate this with:

```
allCoords :: (Num a, Enum a, Num b, Enum b) => a -> b -> [(a, b)]
allCoords h w = (,) <$> [0 .. h-1] <*> [0 .. w-1]
```

Here `(,) <$> [0 .. h-1]` will produce a list of functions `b -> (a, b)` where the first item of the tuple is already filled in. With the `TupleSection`s enabled, this list is equivalent to `[(0,), (1,), …, (w-1,)]`.

Then the `(<*>)` function will take a function from this list, and for each such function call it on each value in the list `[0 .. w-1]`, thus constructing 2-tuples.

For example:

```
Prelude> allCoords 3 4
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
```